# How to show resource usage for the current project only?

Tags: ms-project, resources

In MS Project, is there a way to show resource usage for the current Project only?

When viewing the resource usage report, the totals by resource include allocation for all projects.

Can it be filtered so that the totals show for the current Project only?

Answer (score 1):

Add the column “Project” to the Resource Usage view, and try to filter the view with this column. This should work either if you are using Project Server or a shared resource pool.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening MS Project desktop client again, and when it asks you which profile you want to use (Computer or your PWA/Sharepoint instance), deselect the Load Summary Resource Assignment tick-box. Then only your current project's resource utilization will show.

[image]